# Multithreading in PHP

Tags: php, windows, multithreading

I am working on windows. I have built a twitter application using the twitter API which periodically checks for new tweets as well as allows users to update their status. I have written separate PHP files for reading (reader.php) and writing tweets (writer.php). The only problem is how do I periodically read the tweets. There are a few ways which I can think of -

1) Use a time-based job scheduler (like Cron) to periodically run the reader.php.
How do I do this?

2) Use multithreading to run both reader and writer.php and use a timer function in reader.php

Suggestions?

Comment: Multithreading and Windows?  Use something else.  Why PHP?  It's not the proper tool for your task IMO.

Comment: @shinkou: No, PHP is perfectly well suited to this task. The problem is that the OP is mistaken about this task requiring multi-threading.

Comment: PHP code is very easy to write and smaller as compared to Java..

Comment: Finally, someone else who sees Java as 'bloatware'!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working within Windows, you probably won't be able to use `cron` very easily. You can however, use the task scheduler. See [this](http://www.devx.com/DevX/Article/39900/1763/page/3) link for step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use some kind of job queuing system.  The Zend Server Job Queue has the ability to schedule recurring tasks.  I use it on my site for an awful lot of stuff.  Actually, a lot of what you are trying to do.  It does periodic Twitter searches, processes relationships and such.  I have a posting about how to use it at [Do you queue? Introduction to the Zend Server Job Queue](http://www.eschrade.com/page/queue-introduction-zend-server-queue-4b8eef5c)